# How do I create a PHP file and enter the data to access the URL?

Tags: php, ajax

**I first created a table.**

```
CREATE TABLE testform (
htmlStr MEDIUMTEXT);
```

**After that, I put the data values in that table.**

```
INSERT INTO testform (htmlStr) VALUES ('
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
');
```

**And we want to create a simple button to communicate with Ajax.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    function Add() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<body>
    <button onclick="Add();">ADD PHP</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Below is the background PHP file.**

```
<?php
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/total/end_page/php/dbconn.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testform";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $html = $row['htmlStr'];
    $file = fopen("test3.php","w") or die ("X");
    fwrite($file,$html);
    fclose($file);
    echo "COMPLETE";
?>
```

**test3.php file writes and generates data from the htmlStr column of the testform table.
After that, I accessed the URL where the test3.php file existed, but no value was returned.
When I opened the test3.php file with ftp, the data value of the table was entered correctly, but the value did not appear when I connected to the link.
I want to create a php file to put the html code as text and create that file.

Do you have any feedback?**

**I gave it a try.**

```
fopen("test3.txt","w");
```

**If you connect to the link by making it in txt format instead of php extension, the result value will be output in text format.**

**After that, rename('test3.txt','test3.php'); I tried this.
However, the result shows no value on the page as shown above.

On page F12, we checked the element in the inspection.**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**The tag value in the BODY does not exist.**

Comment: That's not even the HTML structure you posted in your second code. Do you have multiple items in your database? Does a simple `<?php phpinfo() ?>` page work?

Comment: I know it's just a learning exercise, but writing out to a PHP file dynamically is a rare - and dangerous - thing to do. If you just want to store the HTML in the database and then display it, then `echo $html;` is all you need.

Comment: Yes, it works. I received hosting from a place called Cafe24

Comment: Does dynamic file risk mean that if you want to create a page without creating a file, you need to get the form tag value directly from the database without using fopen?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve here. Do you simply want to store html for your pages in your database so it's easy to change, rather than having physical files? Or you want to be able to generate pages made up of ready-made snippets from the database? Or what? The whole thing seems like a confused mishmash of ideas. If you tell us what the point of all this is, we might have a better idea of how to suggest doing it. At the moment it doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense, and your description doesn't really reveal your overall design intention

Comment: P.s. `I received hosting from a place called Cafe24`...that's great, but it's usually a lot easier and quicker to use a development environment on your own machine to build and test your code. Most people only deploy to the hosted environment once that process is complete (i.e. the code is fully tested and ready for real-life usage).

Comment: Initially, we passed the next page-wide HTML value as a parameter in the URL path. However, the URL was long and there was a page error, so I tried to proceed by creating my own php file and putting the html value in the php file, but the person above said that this method is not the right way to do it. So I try to import the data to the DB, but this method is also a way to pass the parameter value, so the URL is long, so it's the same situation.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean. If you need a parameter to say which html comes next, why not use the ID of the relevant row in the database as the parameter? Then it's only a number to pass. Php can then use that number to retrieve the correct item of html from the database and display it. And there you go, you have a simple CMS (Content Management System). There's never any need to pass the whole html string in the request